# Zoom only in x or y direction in pyqtgraph using mouse

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm using [pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/), which has out of the box zoom behaviour using the mouse wheel. However for my application I need to zoom in the x or y direction only.

I wish to do the following:

- Detect mouse click start position: x1, y1
- Drag mouse in x or y direction then release mouse.
- Detect mouse click release position: x2, y2
- Calculate dx = x2-x1 and dy = y2-y1
- If dx > dy, only update x limits of plot to [x1, x2].
- If dy > dx, only update y limits of plot to [y1, y2].

What is the best way to approach this in pyqtgraph?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`setMouseEnabled()`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setMouseEnabled). From the documentation:

```
setMouseEnabled(x=None, y=None)
```

> Set whether each axis is enabled for mouse interaction. x, y arguments must be True or False. This allows the user to pan/scale one axis of the view while leaving the other axis unchanged.

For example

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget() 
plot_widget.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(y=False) # Only allow zoom in X-axis
plot_widget.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(x=False) # Only allow zoom in Y-axis
```

Only X-axis (left), Only Y-axis (right)

[image]
[image]